# Evaluating the integral of $f(x, y)=yx$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the integral $I = \int_C f(x,y) ds$ where $f(x,y)=yx$. and the curve $C$ is given by $x=\sin(t)$ and $y=\cos(t)$ for $0\leq t\leq \frac{pi}{2}$. I got the answer for this as $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ is that right?

Answer (score 3):

$$ \int_C f(x,y) ds = \int_C f(x,y) \sqrt{ (dx)^2 + (dy)^2} $$

Now make the change of variables $x = \sin (t), dx = \cos(t)dt , y = \cos (t), dy = -\sin (t)dt , 0 \leq t \leq \pi/2$. Thus

$$ \int_C f(x,y) ds = \int_0^{\pi/2}  \cos(t) \sin(t) dt = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin(2t) dt$$ $$ = -\frac{1}{4}(\cos( 2(\pi /2) ) - \cos(0))= \frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate the parameterized integral
$$ \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos t \sin t \sqrt{\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t} \, dt = \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos t \sin t \, dt. $$
I don't see a square root of 2 appearing anywhere.

Comment: I guess i did it wrong. is it 1/2?

Answer (score 0):

The line integral of the curve $f(x,y)$ is given by $\int_a^b{f(x,y)ds}$ where $ds=\sqrt{{(\frac{dx}{dt})}^2+{(\frac{dy}{dt})}^2}dt$. In this case $f(x,y)=xy=sin(t)cos(t)$ & $ds=1dt$ so $$\int_0^{\pi/2}{sin(t)cos(t)dt}=\frac12$$.